# building a clock with html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to create a clock using HTML5, canvas and JavaScript.
However I don't understand why when I run the following code with Sublime I can't see anything. I tried to see something using both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.
Maybe the error is in the code?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Clock</title>
    <!--<script src="clockJS.js" ></script>-->
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <img id="myImage" />
    <script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = '28d1fa';
    ctx.linewidth = 17;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    ctx.shadowColor = '28d1fa';

    function degToRad(degree) {
        var factor = Math.PI / 180;
        return degree * factor;
    }

    function renderTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var today = now.toDateString();
        var time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();
        var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
        var newSeconds = seconds + (milliseconds/1000);

        //Background
        gradient = ctx.createRadioGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, '09303a');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'black');
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        //ctx.fillStyle = '333333';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        //Hours
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 200, degToRad(270), degToRad((hours*15)-90));
        ctx.stroke();

        //Minutes
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 170, degToRad(270), degToRad((minutes*6)-90));
        ctx.stroke();

        //Seconds
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, 140, degToRad(270), degToRad((newSeconds*6)-90));
        ctx.stroke();

        //Date
        ctx.font = "23px Arial bold";
        ctx.fillStyle = '28d1fa';
        ctx.fillText(today, 175, 250);

        //Time
        ctx.font = "23px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = '28d1fa';
        ctx.fillText(time, 175, 280);

        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl();

        document.getElementById('myImage').src = dataUrl;

    }

    setInterval(renderTime, 40);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Open your console and read the errors (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). There are numerous spelling/capitalization/format mistakes in the code that error messages will help solve instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Change this lines:

```
var time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
gradient = ctx.createRadioGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl();
```

To this:

```
var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
```

That should get you something into the screen. I recommend you using Chrome's developer console to see all the JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
```